# Copy\delete batch not working correctly

Tags: batch-file, syntax

What this batch does is set an error log, set the DoW and date\time, copies specific files (maintaining directory structure between source and destination), and cleans up the destination based on retention period.  Everything works except the error logging.  The problem is it's not outputting the text to the log the way I want it to and skipping over everything by just going to the exit like it should (for example, it does output the start date\time, the exit sentence "The process completed", and the end date\time - but not any of the error text above that and it still processes the cleanup even if it encounters an errorcode).

I know I've got something wrong in there but I can't figure it out (and everything I've looked up doesn't work either - including speaking to a professional Developer in our organization).  I'm hoping someone here has some ideas as to what's off about this (and yes I know there's probably a better way to do this but this is both what I know and what I've pieced together from existing batch files and research online so I didn't have to reinvent the wheel - it was meant to be a quick and easy solution for a given specific need of copying files from one location to another, keeping that destination location clean, and logging the activity).  So far I've been able to fix other things but this issue.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: So I figured out that the errorlevel being returned when there are no files copied is 0.  But if that's now the case then the syntax reference for the command is not only incorrect but I have no idea to have it deal with a correct exit (that it copied all of the new files found and now needs to complete the cleanup section and move on from there).

```
    @echo off
    SET ERRLOG=c:\backupcopy2.log

    :: ------------------ Date and Time Modifier ------------------------
    :: THIS CODE WILL DISPLAY A 2-DIGIT TIMESTAMP
    :: CREATE VARIABLE %TIMESTAMP%
    for /f "tokens=1-8 delims=.:/-, " %%i in ('echo exit^|cmd /q /k"prompt $D $T"') do (
       for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/-,() skip=1" %%a in ('echo.^|date') do (
    set dow=%%i
    set mm=%%j
    set dd=%%k
    set yy=%%l
    set hh=%%m
    set min=%%n
    set sec=%%o
    set hsec=%%p
    )
    )
    :: ensure that hour is always 2 digits
    if %hh%==0 set hh=00
    if %hh%==1 set hh=01
    if %hh%==2 set hh=02
    if %hh%==3 set hh=03
    if %hh%==4 set hh=04
    if %hh%==5 set hh=05
    if %hh%==6 set hh=06
    if %hh%==7 set hh=07
    if %hh%==8 set hh=08
    if %hh%==9 set hh=09
    :: assign timeStamp:
    :: Add the date and time parameters as necessary - " yy-mm-dd-dow-min-sec-hsec "

    set timeStamp=%mm%%dd%%yy%_%hh%%min%%sec%


    :: --------- TIME STAMP DIAGNOSTICS -------------------------

    :: Un-comment these lines to test output

    :: echo dayOfWeek = %dow%
    :: echo year = %yy%
    :: echo month = %mm%
    :: echo day = %dd%
    :: echo hour = %hh%
    :: echo minute = %min%
    :: echo second = %sec%
    :: echo hundredthsSecond = %hsec%
    :: echo.
    :: echo Hello! 
    :: echo Today is %dow%, %mm%/%dd%/%yy%. 
    :: echo.
    :: echo Your timestamp will look like this: %timeStamp%
    :: echo. 
    :: echo.
    :: echo.
    :: pause

    :: --------- END TIME STAMP DIAGNOSTICS ----------------------

    :: Log start time
    @echo === %dow% %timestamp% : Start === >> %ERRLOG%


    :: Copy latest BAK files from X to Z and retain folder structure
    xcopy x:\*.pbk z:\ /v /q /d /i /s

    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto nofiles
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 4 goto lowmemory
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 5 goto writeerror
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto cleanup

    :nofiles
    echo No files were found to copy >> %ERRLOG%
    goto exit

    :lowmemory 
    echo Insufficient memory to copy files or invalid drive or command-line syntax >> %ERRLOG%
    goto exit 

    :writeerror
    echo A disk write error occurred >> %ERRLOG%
    goto exit

    :: Deletes files older than 30 days - modify the /d to change the retention period
    :cleanup
    for /D %%X IN (z:\0*.) DO forfiles /p %%X /s /m *.pbk /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @file" /d -30

    :exit
    echo The process completed >> %ERRLOG%
    :: Log end time
    :: ------------------ Date and Time Modifier ------------------------
    :: THIS CODE WILL DISPLAY A 2-DIGIT TIMESTAMP
    :: CREATE VARIABLE %TIMESTAMP%
    for /f "tokens=1-8 delims=.:/-, " %%i in ('echo exit^|cmd /q /k"prompt $D $T"') do (
       for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/-,() skip=1" %%a in ('echo.^|date') do (
    set dow=%%i
    set mm=%%j
    set dd=%%k
    set yy=%%l
    set hh=%%m
    set min=%%n
    set sec=%%o
    set hsec=%%p
    )
    )
    :: ensure that hour is always 2 digits
    if %hh%==0 set hh=00
    if %hh%==1 set hh=01
    if %hh%==2 set hh=02
    if %hh%==3 set hh=03
    if %hh%==4 set hh=04
    if %hh%==5 set hh=05
    if %hh%==6 set hh=06
    if %hh%==7 set hh=07
    if %hh%==8 set hh=08
    if %hh%==9 set hh=09
    :: assign timeStamp:
    :: Add the date and time parameters as necessary - " yy-mm-dd-dow-min-sec-hsec "

    set timeStamp=%mm%%dd%%yy%_%hh%%min%%sec%

    @echo === %dow% %timestamp% : End === >> %ERRLOG%
```